Drawing line defined by start and end points within attribute table in QGIS
I am creating a map with multiple labels. For these, I am using Points with Symbols because I have to be able to control the placement very strictly.
I would like to add attribute fields to the Point layer for x and y of the original placement and the one after moving it. (I know how to do this)
Is it possible to now create a line shapefile layer that takes these two coordinate pairs for each point (original placement and new placement) and automatically draws a line between them?
In other words, can you control a line's start and end points through values within another attribute table?

Does the posted answer work? What should I do when someone answers my question?

If you want to display the displacement only graphically in the map you can consider to use the geometry generator with an expression like this one:
make_line($geometry, make_point( "x_old" , "y_old" ))

where $geometry is the current position of the point feature and x_old, y_old are the stored coordinates of the last position.

If you need a new line feature dataset, you can use the same expression with the processing tool geometry by expression

A third option would be to use a virtual layerand to create the geometry using SQL like:
select makeline(makepoint(x_old, y_old), makepoint(x(geometry), y(geometry))) as geom from mylayer


